# What has to be imported for cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE) to work?

Tags: java, itext

I got the instruction to use the line

```
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
```

to align the contents of my cell to the middle.
It gives me an error saying "Element cannot be resolved to a
variable".
I looked it up as best as I could and I found this line

```
com.itextpdf.styledxmlparser.jsoup.select.Elements
```

but when I try to import that I get the error "The import com.itextpdf.styledxmlparser cannot be
resolved".

What do I have to do to get the aligning code to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of iText are you using? Perhaps you should use a version that matches the instructions you're following.

E.g. [iText 5 examples](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it5kb/examples/alignment-indentation-leading-and-spacing-in-cells) show:

```java
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
```

```java
cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
```

[iText 7 examples](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/alignment-indentation-leading-and-spacing-in-cells) show:

```java
import com.itextpdf.layout.property.VerticalAlignment;
```

```java
cell.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I am using iText 7, sadly most of the resources online are for older versions. Another question, I tried to just replace 'Vertical' with 'Horizontal', and that didn't work, could you tell me what should I use for horizontal alignment?

Comment: @MirkóVerő See [setTextAlignment()](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.2/com/itextpdf/layout/ElementPropertyContainer.html#setTextAlignment-com.itextpdf.layout.property.TextAlignment-).